# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

Как разрешить это?
Строка с ошибкой:

```
$req = $this->makeApiCall('users/search/?query='.$username)['users'][0];
```

`PHP 5.3, Ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас версия PHP ниже, чем 5.5, и при объявлении массива нельзя сразу использовать его элементы.

В верх `.htaccess` добавьте следующее:

```
#PHP 5.5

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

Или измените PHP на:

```
$req = $this->makeApiCall('users/search/?query='.$username);
$req = $req['users'][0];
```